# The select/dropdown/combobox of Angular Material2 to display all items or any number of items?

Tags: angular, angular-material, html-select, dropdown, angular-material2

The select component seems to display 5 items at most by default, even if the screen still has a lot vertical realestate. Is there a way to display all items, or define the number of items to be displayed? so the users don't have to always scroll.

Comment: this may help you https://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/dOpbpE?editors=1010#0

Comment: OP asked about dropdown menu, size not "display selected items"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following CSS to your global stylesheet:

```
.mat-select-content {
   height: 600px; 
}
```

Change `600px` to your desired height.

Comment: not working. Such css makes the scrollable area at fixed size 600px, regardless of the options contained.  The displayed options are still 5.